# How can I send emails automatically through my hotmail.com account using python?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

So I've been trying to send an email programmatically using my @hotmail.com account.

What I've succeeded in doing so far:

1. Create an app here https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList and have:

   1. an Application ID
   2. a Password under "Application Secrets
   3. Under plaftorms I've added a web and a Native Application
   4. Under Graph Permissions I've got under Delegated Permissions "Mail.Send" and "User.Read"
2. I've successfully managed to run [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-send-mail) code to send an email through the browser.

   1. However, I was asked to log in as part of the process to authenticate.

The question is the following:

How can I send an email through python and using my @hotmail.com account without having to provide any login credentials each time?

The ideal solution would be a simple `sendmail(to, subject, body)` (or similar) and a config file with an app specific password (which I think I already have).

Initially, I had hoped to look through the sample python code from the above link (repeated [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-send-mail/blob/master/sample.py)) and try to adapt it but that wouldn't be the right approach given the sample code requires a login through the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def SendEmail():
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #Change smtp for Outlook
    s.starttls()
    s.login(EmailGoesHere, PASSWORDHere)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()       # create a message

    # add in the actual person name to the message template
    message = '''
        Message Goes here
    '''

    # Prints out the message body for our sake
    # print(message)

    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['From']=MY_ADDRESS
    msg['To']='ecesisproduction@gmail.com'
    msg['Subject']="Marketplace order Accepted!"

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    # send the message via the server set up earlier.
    s.send_message(msg)

    # Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection
    s.quit()
```

Comment: Happy to Help :)